# c# how to get files name into a specific folder which have a specific pattern

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a folder that contains these files:

```
Erb3PCustsExport-303_20080318_223505_000.xml
Erb3PCustsExport-303_20080319_063109_000_Empty.xml
Erb3PCustsImport-303_20080319_123456.xml
Erb3PDelCustsExport-303_20080319_062410_000.xml
Erb3PResosExport-303_20080318_223505_000_Empty.xml
Erb3PResosExport-303_20080319_062409_000.xml
```

I just care about the files that have `CustsExport` word in their names.

#### My question:

How to get these files?

#### What I have tried:

I got the folder name from `app settings` section in `App.Config` like this:

```
string folderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlFolder"];
```

Then I got all the file names like this:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.xml"))
{

}
```

#### My problem:

In that way, I got all the files. However, I am just interested in files that have `CustsExport` in their names.

Could you help me please?

#### Note:

I am working on .NET 4.5

Comment: A hint: you can check if a string contains another string, or you can specify the file matcher like your doing with *.xml

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*CustsExport*.xml")` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Macro: I Also add regex way to my answer. good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*CustsExport*.xml"))
{

}
```

Or your can use regex:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@".*CustsExport.*\.xml",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var files = Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, "*.xml")
                     .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path))
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Contains("")

```
string folderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlFolder"];
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.xml"))
        {
            if (file.Contains("CustsExport"))
            {
                //add your code
            }
        }
```